# How to decompress GZip in Stream (C#)?

Tags: c#, stream, gzip, gzipstream

This code receives the GZip-encoded string. How can I decode it?

```
Stream stream = ret.GetResponseStream();

System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default);

string answer = reader.ReadToEnd();//answer is GZip encoded string !

byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(answer);

//???

GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

// ... what's next?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One other way is to use Automatic decompression property of the request/response:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Set this property before you get the response.

Comment: Far out, that makes things so much easier!